# Why ruby destroy method is not destroying? (see below)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

## My controller

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy
  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

## my view

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

**Notes from Tutorial Page:**
Here we're using `link_to` in a different way. We pass the named route as the second argument, and then the options as another argument. The `:method` and `'data-confirm'` options are used as HTML5 attributes so that when the link is clicked, Rails will first show a confirm dialog to the user, and then submit the link with method `delete`.

**Whenever I click the delete button, it shows the edit result**

[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Ik7.png)

Comment: What happens if you click the link? Does the confirmation dialog show up? How does the log file entry look like? Do you really follow a tutorial for Rails 4 - or do you use an up-to-date version of Rails? How does your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` look like and do you have a `javascript_include_tag` in your layout?

Comment: In order to really help it would be useful to know, which the comment above me is also asking about, what exactly happens when you do click the link?  And, if you open up inspector are there any errors in the console when you click the button?

Comment: Could your Article class has an has_many relationship? In this case you should also have to handle dependency on destroing it

Comment: I have in my layout <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: my application.js file                    
= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

Comment: Whenever I click the delete button, it shows the edit result

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do to get a more useful exception would be to add a bang `!` to your `destroy` method, which will raise an exception if the destroy fails.

It's possible that there is some failing association validation or callback that is raising an exception that you're not seeing. Try using this for your destroy method and watching your server logs after you click the link:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy!
  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

If you're not seeing anything in your server log, it may be a routing issue

Comment: It won't necessarily make your code work, but it should show you what's wrong in your server logs. If there are no 500 errors in your server logs then the call to `destroy` is no the problem

Comment: I tried to delete from Rails console and its working fine. But whenever I tried to delete from my UI, it ends up showing the Show result :(

Answer (score 0):

Your **controller** code of **destroy action** as well as **view** code of **delete link** seems fine, then in order to exactly dig the reason why it's not working do one thing, just open console and try to manually destroy an article with bang as NM Pennypacker suggested above.

> Article.find(1).destroy!

Answer (score 0):

Initially I got confused little (As I am using lower version of rails), later found and read [this article](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/were-finally-getting-destroy-in-rails-4)

This will clear your idea about other methods also along with `destroy!`